# Remove url portion after ampersand

Tags: javascript

I am passing a url dynamically for a javscript widget using the following

"url": document.location.href,

However the issue is my url is sometimes of the format

http://www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=33&blahblah

However I want to remove all characters after '&' including '&' and make the url

```
http://www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=33
```

How can I do this keeping performance in mind?

Comment: how is your url sometimes of the format `http://www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=33&blahblah`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = document.location.href.split('&', 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'http://www.mysite.com/product.aspx?id=33&blahblah'.split('&').shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

do a split on your URL.

```
urlArr = url.split("&");
```

This will give you an array.

`urlArr[0]` is what u need

Answer (score 0):

```
var _baseUrl = "http://www.example.com/product.aspx?id=33&blahblah";
var _end = _baseUrl.indexOf("&");
if (_end > 0) {
    _end++;
} else {
    _end = _baseUrl.length
}
var _finalUrl = _curUrl.slice(0, _end);
```